# Rails - Select records where active storage link does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using rails active storage and I want to know if it is possible to create a scope where i can pull users who are missing the profile image

Suppose I have the following `User` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I know I can check if the image is linked with the object via following

```
user.avatar.attached?
```

But what if I want to pull those users from database who are missing the avatar? I am sure there is a better way than pulling all users and looping through them to find the users who have no `avatar`

Any tip will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [join](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32295) and get all the user with avatar and subtract them to all users like that:

```
@no_avatar_users = User.all - User.joins(:avatar)
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this will work as avatar is not a column in database